# How to replace value in CSV file

Tags: c++, csv

I have CSV file build like this:

```
1;name;2;5;
2;diff_name;3;5;
```

And I would like to be able to replace the 5 with 2 before reading the next line.
So I am reading the file:

```
file>>number1;
file.ignore( numeric_limits < streamsize >::max(), ';' );
file>>data;
```

and so on. And I was trying to write it this way:

```
long pos = plik.tellp();
plik.seekp (pos-2);
plik<<other_number;
```

But it breaks the file. I don't know how but it's not reliable. the pos somehow depends on the file lenght and I can't make it work every time (with different valuse in file) this way. Is there some other way to replace the value here? Is there an easy way?

Comment: Read all data from the file, line by line, and write everything to another file, changing the value you want to change. Then rename the new file as the old file (thereby overwriting it).

Comment: You'll need to provide details on exactly what you're seeing and what you expected to see instead.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Joachim Pileborg in a comment, you can't really (and simply) directly replace in the file. The solution is to write in an other file. If your first file is enough small, you can use your memory in place of a second file, and write the result in the first file.

My code :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  ifstream ifile("file.csv"); //First file
  ofstream ofile("filenew.csv"); //File with replaced fields
  char s[100];
  string temp;//useful for the replacement
  int count=0;//fields counter (useful for replacement)
  while(ifile.good()){
    ifile.getline(s, 100, ';'); //We read the file field by field
    count++;
    if(ifile.good()){
      if(count==3){ //The third field is stored in a temp variable
        temp = s;
      }
      else if(count==4){//And we put the fourth field before the third
        ofile << s;
        ofile << ';';
        ofile << temp;
        ofile << ';';
        count=0;
      }
      else{
        if(count==5)count=0;
        ofile << s;
        ofile << ';';
      }
    }
  }
}
```